# Fire event when owl carousel(2.3) reaches to the last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using owl carousel, in bootstrap modal pop up,for last slide need to close the popup,

I was trying with the following code, but no luck, is there any way ,where I can fire event on last owl slider , to close modal popup

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
         loop:true,
         dots:true,
         nav:true,
         items:1,
         autoplay: false,
         autoplayTimeout: 7000,
             autoplaySpeed: 1400,
         autoplayHoverPause: true,
         navigation: false,
         slideSpeed: 300,
         paginationSpeed: 400,
         singleItem: true,
         autoHeight: true,
         afterMove: moved,
       })

       function moved() {
        $(".owl-carousel").on('change.owl.carousel', function(e) { 

          var total = e.item.count, // # of total items
          itemsPerPage = e.page.size, // # of items that appear per page
          itemGoOut = e.item.index, // index of last item that appeared then went out (index start with 0)
          itemRemain = total - (itemsPerPage + itemGoOut + 1);

          if(itemRemain === 0){
              console.log("No more Items");
          }

          });
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below code and use `changed.owl.carousel` event:

```js
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  loop: false,
  dots: true,
  nav: true,
  items: 1,
  autoplay: false,
  autoplayTimeout: 7000,
  autoplaySpeed: 1400,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  navigation: false,
  slideSpeed: 300,
  paginationSpeed: 400,
  singleItem: true,
  autoHeight: true,
});

let isOver = 0;

$(".owl-carousel").on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
  var current = e.item.index + 1;
  total = e.item.count;
  if (current === total) {
    isOver = 1;
  }
});

$('.owl-next').click(function() {
  if (isOver === 1) {
    isOver = isOver + 1
  } else if (isOver === 2) {
    alert('now close!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha256-UhQQ4fxEeABh4JrcmAJ1+16id/1dnlOEVCFOxDef9Lw=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha256-pTxD+DSzIwmwhOqTFN+DB+nHjO4iAsbgfyFq5K5bcE0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

---

Alright, actually you can not run any function after owl carousel reaches to the end, because it return `false` and won't return anything at all, you can do this with a tricky way, also you need turn off your `loop` setting to get better result. In this trick I just set and condition after it reaches to the end:

Comment: as per the question you answer is right but it fire the code before last slide display.and if try to close the model according it it will close the model after last - 1 slide not at last slide

Comment: @HiteshTripathi it is working ,but it need to close the modal , after last slide load,

Comment: @ishfaq You right, because owl carousel avoid to return `current` item after it reach last, it mean we do not get any data from owl when it reach to end, I working on it. let me check and find a tricky solution, I will update my post

Comment: @ishfaq try new solution